# Final element in an array displays strange behaviour using React Draggable

Tags: reactjs, draggable

I am trying to create logic that when a user clicks drags a card it becomes "active" and when user clicks "x" it becomes inactive again. This sort of works but I find there is some strange flicker (perhaps a rerender) often when the cards are dragged. Most problematically when the final card in the `inactiveCards` array is dragged, and in the process made `active`, it snaps back to its original position. This only occurs for the final card in the array. When it is the first card moved then it works okay but as soon as another card is moved it snaps back again. I can't figure out where in the logic the mistake is happening. Any advice would be helpful.

```
export function App() {
  const [activeCards, setActiveCards] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [inactiveCards, setInactiveCards] = useState<any[]>([]);

  function handleDismissCard(
    e: React.MouseEvent,
    dismissedCard: string,
    index: number
  ) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    // Update activeCards state by filtering out the dismissed card.
    setActiveCards((prevActiveCards) => {
      return prevActiveCards.filter((card) => card !== dismissedCard);
    });

    setInactiveCards((prevInactiveCards) => {
      // Create a shallow copy of prevInactiveCards to avoid modifying the original array 
      const newInactiveCards = [...prevInactiveCards];

      // Insert the dismissed card at the specified index using the splice method.
      newInactiveCards.splice(index, 0, dismissedCard);
      return newInactiveCards;
    });
  }

  function handleUpdateInactiveCards(i: number) {
    setInactiveCards((prevInactiveCards) => {
      return prevInactiveCards.filter((_, index) => index !== i);
    });
  }

  function handleUpdateActiveCards(
    e: React.MouseEvent,
    info: string,
    i: number
  ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    if (activeCards.includes(info)) {
      return;
    }
    // Update activeCards state using functional update 
    setActiveCards((prevActiveCards) => {
      const newActiveCards = [...prevActiveCards, info];
      return newActiveCards;
    });

    handleUpdateInactiveCards(i);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (selected === "Phonics") {
      const phonicsData = spellingData.map((w: Spelling, i: number) => {
        return (
          <Draggable>
            <div
              onClick={(e) => handleUpdateActiveCards(e, w.spelling, i)}
              key={i}>
              <div
                onClick={(e) => handleDismissCard(e, w.spelling, i)} >
                <div>
                  x
                </div>
              </div>
              <h1>
                {w.spelling}
              </h1>
           </div>
          </Draggable>
        );
      });
      setInactiveCards(phonicsData);
    }

    [..]
  }, [selected, activeCards]);

  return (
    <>
      <ActivityCanvas />
      <ResourceBoard learningResource={inactiveCards} />
    </>
  );
}
```